# Convert a custom date format string to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: php, date, datepicker, date-format

I have this **date format** that looks somewhat like this:

> Sun Jun 29 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)

This results from the **x-editable datepicker** when I try to output the value it gets from a validate function.

But, regardless of where I get the date format from, how do I convert this date to `yyyy/mm/dd` format? It’s not a date object but really just a long string that outputs the above. And I need to be able to convert it to **2014-06-29**. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a regular expression to extract the relevant part of your string and then apply PHP date functions to it:

```
$str = "Sun Jun 29 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)";
$pat = "/(?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat) (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} GMT\\+[0-9]{4}/";
$date = preg_match($pat, $str, $mat) ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime($mat[0])) : "";
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/104918)

Comment: You forgot the string "(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)".. it makes the converted date wrong .. it outputs '1970-01-01'. How do i get rid of this? Thank you! :)

Comment: Anyway, i like the strtotime idea.. but i found a solution preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$dateString);  which actually removes all the strings inside parenthesis. But thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Using a regular expression like the one in my answer will also validate your date string. But if you simply need the part of your string before the opening parenthesis, you may go for: `strstr($str, "(", true)` which will be faster than any regular expression alternative.

Comment: @muffin You mean `preg_replace('~\s*\(.+?\)\s*$~', '', $str)`?